# Number instead of the candidates name change

Tags: java

```
import uulib.GUI;
import java.util.Scanner;
import uulib.Num;
/**
 * Write a description of class votes1 here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class votes1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        String[]name=new String[6]; //candidates name
        int[]vote=new int[6]; //candidates vote
        int total_votes=0; //total votes
        double[] percentage = new double[6]; //candidates percentage

        int threshold=GUI.getInt("Enter threshold");
        for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++){
            System.out.println("Enter candidates last name");
            name[i]=in.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter the total votes for " + name[i]);
            vote[i]=in.nextInt();
            total_votes+=vote[i];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<vote.length;i++){
            percentage[i]=(double) vote[i]/(double)total_votes*100.0;
        }

        int bel_threshold=vote[0];
        int winner=vote[0];
        for(int i=1;i<vote.length;i++)
        {
            if(vote[i]>winner)
            {
                winner=vote[i];
            }

            while(vote[i]<threshold){
                bel_threshold=vote[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Candidate"+"\t"+"Votes"+"\t"+"%");
        for(int i=0;i<vote.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(name[i]+"\t" + " \t"+vote[i]+"\t"+ Num.format(percentage[i],1));
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Total votes"+"\t" +total_votes);
        System.out.println("Threshold" +"\t"+ threshold);
        System.out.println("Winner: " + "\t" + winner);
        System.out.println("Below threshold"+"\t" + " \t" + bel_threshold);

    }   
}
```

For the winner and below_threshold it shows the number of the low and high votes, i want to display the names of the candidates. How can i print the winner and below_threshold candidates name instead of their vote?

Comment: I am afraid you need to show more codes than this. Do you have a class?

Comment: I have posted the whole class

Comment: I've added a complete solution with explanation below, take a look at it. It should help you for now and for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the index in `winner` (not the votes). Like

```
int winner = 0;
for(int i=1;i<vote.length;i++)
{
  if(vote[i]>vote[winner]){
    winner = i;
  }
}
```

Then print the winner like,

```
System.out.println("Winner: " + name[winner]);
```

Comment: How can i print more than one name for the bel_threshold. i have done it the same way you have shown me for the winner.

Comment: By storing more than one value. Perhaps in a `Collection` like `ArrayList`.

Comment: `List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>(); al.add(1); al.add(2); System.out.println(al);` should be `1,2`.

Answer (score 0):

**String[ ] name:**

```
+----+----+----+----+
| 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |  <--Array index
+----+----+----+----+
|Cdd1|Cdd2|Cdd3|Cdd4|  <--Names of Candidates (String array)
+----+----+----+----+
```

**int[ ] vote:**

```
+----+----+----+----+
| 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |  <--Array index
+----+----+----+----+
|120 |550 |330 |220 |  <--Votes of Candidates (int array)
+----+----+----+----+
```

This is what we call **parallel arrays**. 
Meaning that same index corresponds to the same person.
Since the array index for name[] and vote[] matches, 
the **index of the highest** vote **will also be** the **index of the name** (candidate)
with the highest vote.

Since you used `winner` to hold the index of the highest vote, just use `winner` again as the index to print out the name with the highest vote.

To print **winner's name**, simply do this:

```
System.out.println("Winner: " + "\t" + name[winner]);
```

---

It is easy to **print** out the names of the **candidates below threshold**. I think you don't need to store the candidates names right? You can just call a very **simple method** to do that:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //Candidates below threshold
    print_Below_Threshold(threshold, name, votes);
}

public static void print_Below_Threshold(int threshold, String[] name, int[] votes){
    for(int x=0; x<name.legnth; x++)
        if(votes[x] < threshold)
            System.out.print(name[x] + " ");    
}
```

If you are not allowed to use method for any reason, just write the 3 lines of codes directly in your main where you need to print the candidates below threshold.